# How many 3-digit numbers divisible by 3 have no digits that are individually divisible by 3?

Tags: combinatorics, divisibility

By manual counting, I reached an answer of 90.

However, I want to know the most efficient way possible, which would likely be complementary counting.

The number of 3 digit numbers divisible by 3 is $\frac{999}3-\frac{99}3=300$.

Let ABC be the three digit number (where A, B, and C are the digits).

Case 1: 3BC, 6BC, 9BC (BC is a 2-digit number where neither B nor c are divisible by 3.) There are $\frac{99}3-(4*4)+1=18$ of these cases. $18*3=54$

Case 2: A3C, A6C, A9C (AC is a 2-digit number where neither A nor C are divisible by 3. There are $\frac{99}3-(3*4)=21$ of these cases.) $21*3=63$

Case 3: AB3, AB6, AB9. It has the same number of cases as case 2. $21*3=63$

Case 4: The remainder of cases: $3*4*4=48$

$300-(54+63+63+28)=92$

Why is the efficient way wrong?

Comment: I presume you meant $300$ in your third line?

Comment: Yes, I updated it.

Comment: You are probably double counting or sneaking 0s into there.

Comment: "3BC, 6BC, 9BC (BC is a 2-digit number where neither B nor c are divisible by 3.) There are 99/3−(4∗4)+1=18"  Huh?  Aren't there $3*(7*7)$ of these.  And you make no attempt to weed the multiples of three out.  This .... I don't understand your reasoning at all.

Comment: 99/3 indicates the number of 2-digit numbers divisible by 3 that have digits not divisible by 3. (4*4) is choosing one from each of the sets for A {0, 3, 6, 9} and B {0, 3, 6, 9}. +1 comes from if BC is 00. I don't understand $3*(7*7)$

Comment: Could you explain based on your manual counting what is wrong with the elementary solution that I gave? Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: 1BC, 4BC, 7BC: 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 42, 45, 48, 51, 54, 57, 72, 75, 78, 81, 84, 87 Edit: I accidentally hit enter

Comment: Wait for revision

Comment: Oh, Arnaud I think I excluded 0 as being divisible by 3. You consider 0 to be divisible by 3 (which is more technically correct).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two cases to consider.  If we exclude the digit zero as divisible by 3 then we have just 6 digits to choose from, namely, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8.  To modulo 3 these are respectively, +1, -1, +1, -1, +1, -1.  To make a three digit number divisible by 3 (because 10 is 1 modulo 3) we need all digits to be either +1 or all -1 modulo 3.  This means that we can have 3x3x3 combinations of digits with +1 "parity" and the same number to -1, giving a total of 54 combinations.

Now, if we wish to include the digit zero, then we must have two digits of opposite "parity" with the zero in either the last or middle position.  This gives 3x3x2 twice or 36 more - a total of 90 as you have counted manually.

Comment: Why would zero be allowed?

Comment: Oh, I just realized that I disregarded that.

Answer (score 2):

The only allowed digits are $1,2,4,5,7,8$.

Modulo $3$, the options are $1$ or $2$.

Assume that you have picked the first two digits. If they are different modulo $3$, then there is no way to complete the number.

If the first two digits *are* congruent modulo $3$, then there are $3$ options for the last one. There are $6\times 3\times 3=54$ numbers so formed.